# Limit internet bandwidth

Tags: windows-8, traffic-shaping

For test purposes (to debug my WindowsPhone7 application), I need to limit the network speed to a small value, like 79 kbits/sec. I’m using Windows 8 x64.

- NetLimiter doesn’t install at all.
- NetBalancer displays bandwidth usage of the process I’m interested in (it’s WmZuneComm.exe BTW) zero bytes/sec, even while I’m absolutely sure it consumes 8000 bytes/sec playing streaming audio (and Windows built-in resource monitor shows me that).
- Also, I have Asus RT-N56U router. I’ve just flashed the latest unofficial firmware ver. 3.0.3.4-048. Unlike official one, it has the guest access point feature. Unfortunately, bandwidth limit still can’t be imposed.

I’m OK if the solution will limit not just a single application, but the whole system. I only need to perform a few tests on a slow network. It's OK if the solution will only limit the download speed.

Any ideas how do I do that?

Comment: can you block certain websites on the guest point?

Comment: @dashboard, AFAIK you can't - there're very few settings about that guest AP.

Comment: Did you run Net Balancer 'as administrator'?

Comment: Did you try using your router's built in QoS at all?

Answer (score 3):

I would opt to use the router's built in QoS first like what techie007 suggested. If it doesn't meet all your requirements then that's the time you can look into a Software control mechanism.

Comment: Thanks. Restored the official firmware, discovered the QoS settings. However, the built-in shaper works really bad, it's too spiky. When bandwidth is throttled to 79 kbit/sec, neither my WP7 app, nor winamp plays 40 kbit/sec streams :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Bandwidth Controller](http://bandwidthcontroller.com/) at an enterprise level in the past and it works like a charm.

Its key features are:

> 1. Layer 3 bandwidth manager
> 2. TCP/IP stream limiting and prioritization
> 3. Distributed mode for client-only networks
> 4. Traffic monitoring
> 5. Remote management
> 6. Deep Packet Inspection
> 7. Guaranteed rate provision
> 8. Internet speeds from 56 kbps to 2,400 Mbps
> 9. Wireless network support
> 10. Up to 2,000 concurrent users

There seems to be a 30 day trial available, so i think its worth it to give it a chance.

Comment: Bandwidth Controller is long abandoned, I think it is only supported by Windows systems up to Windows 2003. Despite its the best speed controller for Windows I know, it is full of issues that never get fixed. It is very unstable and will eventually freeze your server, the rules tables get corrupted and you have to configure everything manually, some settings are not saved correctly and have to be redefined upon booting etc.

Comment: @Havenard thank you for the info, i am shocked; i used this software for over 2 years and never had any kind of trouble.